# Cross-project iframe testing on localhost with different ports

Tags: django, iframe

I am relatively new to iFrame, and what I try to do is to load *project A* in an `iframe` that is in *project B*. Project A is running as a Django project on localhost:8000, and project B as a separate Django project on localhost:8001. Inside the project B, I have a Django template with the following content:

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>
```

The problem is that instead of seeing the content of project A home page, I see error message stating that:

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Is there anything I am terribly missing?

Comment: No, I have edited the question. The issue is not in recursive calls

Comment: Ah, this is the Clickjacking Protection by Django kicking in. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/

Comment: Yeap) I've alreadtly figured that out :) But you can post your comment as answer, I will tick that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default [Clickjacking Protection [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/clickjacking/) by Django kicking into action (Great for us!), but this is preventing you from loading the iframe in your other project. There are various options to solve this issue:

1. If you want all your pages from your project to be put inside an iframe then you can remove `'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'` from your `MIDDLEWARE` settings:

   ```python
   MIDDLEWARE = [
        ...
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        ...
    ]
   ```
2. If this is for only specific views you can use the `xframe_options_exempt` decorator:

   ```python
   from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

   @xframe_options_exempt
   def some_view(request):
       ...
   ```